# Choosing Features for K mean clustering

Tags: machine-learning

I wanted to do a simple project to practice using K mean clustering, and I was thinking about trying to cluster stocks that behave similarly over time. My initial plan was to pull data from the Yahoo Finance API and then use the daily movements of a stock (going back a few years) as the feature space.

Is this an acceptable way of approaching the problem? I do not have much experience other than from contrived examples, so I am not sure how one usually decides what features to use in practice. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds appropriate to me based on [other resources](http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/time-series-clustering-classification).